# Is it possible to create anonymous objects in Python?

Tags: python, anonymous-types

I'm debugging some Python that takes, as input, a list of objects, each with some attributes.

I'd like to hard-code some test values -- let's say, a list of four objects whose "foo" attribute is set to some number.

Is there a more concise way than this?

```
x1.foo = 1
x2.foo = 2
x3.foo = 3
x4.foo = 4
myfunc([x1, x2, x3, x4])
```

Ideally, I'd just like to be able to say something like:

```
myfunc([<foo=1>, <foo=2>, <foo=3>, <foo=4>])
```

(Obviously, that is made-up syntax. But is there something similar that really works?)

Note: This will never be checked in. It's just some throwaway debug code. So don't worry about readability or maintainability.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I like Tetha's solution, but it's unnecessarily complex.

Here's something simpler:

```
>>> class MicroMock(object):
...     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
...         self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
...
>>> def print_foo(x):
...     print x.foo
...
>>> print_foo(MicroMock(foo=3))
3
```

Comment: However, if you're creating a whole bunch of these, you might save some time/memory by using the given dictionary instead of creating a new one and copying all the entries. Doesn't *really* matter, though.

Comment: well, I might be subjective, but I see no substantial simplification. Yes, you use __init__ and update, but youre still fiddling around with __dict__.

Comment: You're right, there's no significant simplification. It's just shorter and doesn't use __new__, that's all.

Comment: If you want convenient syntax, `_` is a valid class name in python, and isn't really any more indecipherable than the version posited in the question.

Comment: With recent Python feature, you can use "def mock(**kwargs): return type('',(),kwargs)()", and do "a = mock(foo=1)"

Comment: Since Python 3.3 (2012) you can just use Mock class from the standard library (unittest.mock.Mock) instead of a custom class https://stackoverflow.com/a/75360777/1161025

Answer (score 84):

I found this: http://www.hydrogen18.com/blog/python-anonymous-objects.html, and in my limited testing it seems like it works:

```
>>> obj = type('',(object,),{"foo": 1})()
>>> obj.foo
1
```

Comment: Brilliant! And is true one-liner!

Comment: Love it. This also works with other classes and initializing, for example here’s an anonymous object derived from Python’s dictionary and initialized with two entries: `type("", (dict,), {})({"a": 1, "b": 2})`

Comment: using mock object it's even simpler, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75360777/1161025

Answer (score 41):

Wow, so brief, such Python! O.o

```
>>> Object = lambda **kwargs: type("Object", (), kwargs)
```

Then you can use `Object` as a generic object constructor:

```
>>> person = Object(name = "Bernhard", gender = "male", age = 42)
>>> person.name
'Bernhard'
>>>
```

Now technically this creates a class object, not an object object. But you can treat it like an anonymous object or you modify the first line by appending a pair of parenthesis to create an immediate instance:

```
>>> Object = lambda **kwargs: type("Object", (), kwargs)()
```

Comment: This is the only "non-horrible" solution I've seen here.

Comment: Nice. Should be a PEP to add a new keyword. Maybe change the name from `Object` to `Anon` though?

Comment: Alternatively, `    def thingy(**kwargs):
        return type("Object", (), kwargs)()
`

Answer (score 16):

Have a look at this:

```
class MiniMock(object):
    def __new__(cls, **attrs):
        result = object.__new__(cls)
        result.__dict__ = attrs
        return result

def print_foo(x):
    print x.foo

print_foo(MiniMock(foo=3))
```

Answer (score 16):

Maybe you can use [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) to solve this as following:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Mock = namedtuple('Mock', ['foo'])

mock = Mock(foo=1)
mock.foo  // 1
```

Answer (score 11):

I will use lambda

```
obj = lambda: None
obj.s = 'abb'
obj.i = 122
```

Comment: What is the difference with `obj = {}`?

Comment: @AndersLindén You'll get AttributeError with `{}`, one cannot set attributes on a `dict`.

Comment: aaaand we have a real answer. +million.. I'm done using a dict as a container for 
relatively simple objects that I don't want to create a class for. 
One minor inconvenience: if you need to JSON serialize this, you need to use obj.__dict__
That's an inconvenience I'm willing to live with.

Answer (score 9):

As of Python 3.3, there's [types.SimpleNamespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace) that does exactly what you want:

```
myfunc([types.SimpleNamespace(foo=1), types.SimpleNamespace(foo=2), types.SimpleNamespace(foo=3), types.SimpleNamespace(foo=4)])
```

That's a tad wordy, but you can clean it up with an alias:

```
_ = types.SimpleNamespace
myfunc([_(foo=1), _(foo=2), _(foo=3), _(foo=4)])
```

And now that's actually pretty close to the fictional syntax in your question.

Comment: Credit to @RoadieRich for suggesting `_` as the class name in an earlier comment.

Comment: If using _ bothers you (it feels a bit icky and unpythonic to me), and you really don't want to type so much, you can also just `from types import SimpleNamespace as Nsp` and use Nsp like _ in your answer.

Comment: @JJC of course! The coding standards I currently work under don't allow renaming on import like that, so I tend to forget that's even an option.

Answer (score 8):

Another obvious hack:

```
class foo1: x=3; y='y'
class foo2: y=5; x=6

print(foo1.x, foo2.y)
```

But for your exact usecase, calling a function with anonymous objects directly, I don't know any one-liner less verbose than

```
myfunc(type('', (object,), {'foo': 3},), type('', (object,), {'foo': 4}))
```

Ugly, does the job, but not really.

Answer (score 8):

```
anonymous_object = type('',(),{'name':'woody', 'age':'25'})()
anonymous_object.name
> 'woody'
```

There is a cool way but hard to understand. 
It use type() create a no-named class with default init params,
then init it without any param and get the anonymous object.

Comment: Python should support anonymous types.  They are very handy in C#.  This is the cleanest solution out of all the answers.

Comment: @michael Yes, it's one of C# 's cool features. C# has a really nice syntax design.

Answer (score 3):

Non classy:

```
def mock(**attrs):
    r = lambda:0
    r.__dict__ = attrs
    return r 

def test(a, b, c, d):
    print a.foo, b.foo, c.foo, d.foo

test(*[mock(foo=i) for i in xrange(1,5)])
# or
test(mock(foo=1), mock(foo=2), mock(foo=3), mock(foo=4))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from unittest.mock import Mock
>>> obj = Mock(foo=1)
>>> obj.foo
1
```

I was surprised to not find this in the answers already.

```
myfunc([Mock(foo=1), Mock(foo=2), Mock(foo=3), Mock(foo=4)])
```

I think it and [`SimpleNamespace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45178188/1161025) are the most straight-forward and "canonical" ways to create a dummy/anonymous object in Python. They work since Python 3.3 (2012). I would base the choice of one of them depending on the context of usage.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I did it:

```
from mock import patch
import requests

class MockResponse:

    def __init__(self, text, status_code):
        self.text = text
        self.status_code = status_code


class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('requests.get',return_value=MockResponse('the result',200))
    def test_some_request(self, *args, **kwargs):
        response = requests.get('some.url.com')
        assert response.text=='the result'
        assert response.status_code=='200'
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Python 3.7 or above, you can use [named tuples](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) to enhance the created object with immutability, docstring, and handy tuple methods:

```py
from collections import namedtuple

PyObj = lambda **kwargs: namedtuple('PyObj', kwargs.keys())._make(kwargs.values())

o = PyObj(foo = 1)
print(o)
# prints: PyObj(foo=1)
o.foo
# returns: 1
o.foo = 0
# exception:
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# AttributeError: can't set attribute

print(PyObj(foo = 1, bar = 'baz'))
# prints: PyObj(foo=1, bar='baz')
```

Python 3.7+ is required to ensure keys and values are in the same order.

However, if the list of attributes is predefined, you can use `namedtuple` directly, as [Huachao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3282254/huachao) suggested, there's no need to define the `PyObj` function and you can use it in v2.7.

```py
from collections import namedtuple
foo = namedtuple('Foo', 'foo')

myfunc = lambda l: [x.foo * 10 for x in l]
myfunc([foo(1), foo(2), foo(3), foo(4)])
# returns [10, 20, 30, 40]
```

Plus, it looks more like the syntax you are looking for.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, I very much missed the straightforward anonymous objects in JavaScript, particularly in function return values, where you can just say

```
function george() { 
    return {fred:6, jim:9}; 
}
x = george();
y = x.fred;
```

You can use a dictionary to get the same effect, but all those square brackets and single quotes look muddly.  So I now do the following, which works:

```
def fred():
    class rv:
        x=0
    rv.y = 6
    return rv

def jim():
    class rv:
        x=0
    rv.y = 9
    return rv
a = fred()
b = jim()
print(a.y, b.y, id(a.y), id(b.y))
```

It would feel nicer to have a global class RV, and instantiate it to get the same effect, but this way the function has no external dependencies.