# In Jython, can I make an inline anonymous class that implements a Java interface?

Tags: java, jython, anonymous-class

In Java, I can say

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
    public void run(){ // do stuff }
}
```

(or something much like that) to declare an anonymous class inline.  This is most useful for making event handlers or other callback sorts of things, that in any *sensible* language [wouldn't require an object to own them](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html) in the first place.

I face the same problem in Jython -- I want to define an event handler, but I don't want to build a whole standalone class to do so.

Ideally, I'd just be able to pass a lambda and be done with it, but if this is possible, I can't find it anywhere in the docs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357997/does-python-have-something-like-anonymous-inner-classes-of-java

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123000/does-python-have-anonymous-classes

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652276/is-it-possible-to-create-anonymous-objects-in-python

Comment: David: This is exactly what I was asking, if you make your comment an answer I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the background-reading links from my original answer:

Read this: [Does Python have something like anonymous inner classes of Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357997/does-python-have-something-like-anonymous-inner-classes-of-java)

Then, read this: [Does Python have anonymous classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123000/does-python-have-anonymous-classes)

Finally, read this: [Is it possible to create anonymous objects in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652276/is-it-possible-to-create-anonymous-objects-in-python)

**[IMPROVEMENT TO ORIGINAL ANSER]**

Jython implicitly converts a function to an event handler when appropriate.  So, you can write this inside of one of your methods:

```
def _(self, event):
    print 'Cancel button was clicked!'
    if self.task is not None:
        self.task.cancel()
cancelButton.setOnAction(lambda event: _(self, event))
```

This approach provides three of desirable characteristics of an anonymous inner class.

(1) It is highly **localized**.  The handler code is next to the code that assigns the handler.

(2) It is **self aware**, meaning you have `self` and can access to all of the members of the containing object.

(3) It is (almost) **anonymous**.  Python forces me to choose a name for multi-line function, but it also allows me to reuse that name.  So, I can define as many local functions called `_` as long as I use them right away.  (Defining a second function by the same name makes the first function inaccessible by that name.)  So, I am not forced to invent unique names ad-infinitum.

You can also package this pattern in a decorator, which I think clarifies the intent a bit:

```
@LocalEventHandler(self, cancelButton.setOnAction)
def _(self, event):
    print 'Cancel button was clicked!'
    if self.task is not None:
        self.task.cancel()
```

The decorator implementation looks like this:

```
class LocalEventHandler(object):
    '''This decorator turns a local function into a *self aware* event handler.'''

    def __init__(self, context, assignHandlerFunc):
        self.context = context
        self.assignHandlerFunc = assignHandlerFunc

    def __call__(self, handler):
        self.assignHandlerFunc(lambda event: handler(self.context, event))
        return handler
```

Comment: Potential problem: I tried this approach to adding a `ChangeListener` to through `ReadOnlyObjectProperty.addListener()`.  But, `addListener()` is overloaded and Jython picks the 'wrong' overloaded function.  What I end up with is an `InvalidationListener` instead of a `ChangeListener`.